# WPF FramePage to MainWindow Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, frame

I have very easy setup. I have `MainWindow.xaml` which on load "unhides" `Frame1` which shows `Page1.xaml`.

I have a button on `Page1.xaml`. How could I use the buttons click event (Page1) to ether close or hide `Page1.xaml & Frame1`, returning the users view to `MainWindow.xaml` (content)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a handle on the main page like this:

```
Dim mainPage As MainWindow = TryCast(Application.Current.MainWindow, MainWindow)
If mainPage IsNot Nothing The mainPage.frame1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

Comment: Thanks.  Error" RootVisual is not a member of System.Windows.Application" Also did you mean "  If Not mainPage Is Nothing Then
            mainPage.Frame1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        End If
"

Comment: Sorry that was Silverlight. I think this is the equivalent.